# Android : countdown

Tags: android, countdown

I would like that the users of my application can insert an hour of a day and I want to display a countdown with dd:hh:mm:ss, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class? Seems like that could do what you want.

Comment: But how can format the milliseconds to days : hours : minutes : seconds  ?